# SQL Query with one to many left join exclude any not existing

Tags: mysql, postgresql, jpa

I would like to run sql query that brings me the children who did not eat any cake between 2 dates. 
2 Tables:

```
* Child 
  - id, name

* Cake
  - child_id, eat_timestamp
```

One child (Andy) has eaten 2 cakes: 10.01.2019 and 11.01.2019

And I would like to search between 09.01.2019 - 10.01.2019.
So Andy should not appear in the list but because of left join, it will display him because it matches the second date (11.01.2019)

```
select * from children c LEFT JOIN
      public.cake cake 
      ON ((cake.child_id = c.id) 
      AND 
      (
          0 = 
         (
            SELECT
               COUNT(cake2.id) 
            FROM
               public.customer t13,
               public.cake cake2 
            WHERE
               (
((cake2.child_id = t13.id) 
                  AND 
                  (
                     cake2.time_planned >= '2019-01-09 00:00:00.0' 
                  )
) 
                  AND 
                  (
                     cake2.time_planned <= '2019-01-10 23:59:59.999' 
                  )
)
```

Comment: Is it MySQL or PostgreSQL?

Comment: PostgreSQL but I guess the solution cane applied to MySQL as well

Comment: Please add some sample data and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with NOT EXISTS:

```
select c.* from children c
where not exists (
  select 1 from cake
  where 
    child_id = c.id 
    and 
    eat_timestamp between '2019-01-09 00:00:00.0' and '2019-01-10 00:00:00.0'
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT c.*
FROM child c
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT child_id
  FROM cake c
  WHERE eat_timestamp NOT BETWEEN '2019-01-09' AND '2019-01-11'
) ck ON c.id = ck.child_id
;
```